# Como inserir valores no gráfico gauge

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart

Estou com widget gauger (Tipo velocimetro) e gostaria de inserir meu próprio valor

Por exemplo, o valor maximo seria 200 e mínimo 0

O valor para setar seria 175

Como faço para inserir valores no gauge?

Como compreender esse código?

```
function init_gauge() {
            if ("undefined" != typeof Gauge) {
                console.log("init_gauge [" + $(".gauge-chart").length + "]"), console.log("init_gauge");
                var a = {
                    lines: 12,
                    angle: 0,
                    lineWidth: .4,
                    pointer: {
                        length: .75,
                        strokeWidth: .042,
                        color: "#1D212A"
                    },
                    limitMax: "false",
                    colorStart: "#1ABC9C",
                    colorStop: "#1ABC9C",
                    strokeColor: "#F0F3F3",
                    generateGradient: !0
                };
                if ($("#chart_gauge_01").length)
                    var b = document.getElementById("chart_gauge_01"),
                    c = new Gauge(b).setOptions(a);

                if ($("#gauge-text").length &&
                      (c.maxValue = 6e3, c.animationSpeed = 32, c.set(1690), c.setTextField(document.getElementById("gauge-text"))),
                      $("#chart_gauge_02").length
                   )

                    var d = document.getElementById("chart_gauge_02"),
                    e = new Gauge(d).setOptions(a);

                $("#gauge-text2").length && (e.maxValue = 9e3, e.animationSpeed = 32, e.set(2400), e.setTextField(document.getElementById("gauge-text2")))
            }
        }
```

O que significa esse 6a3? Eu alterei algumas coisas, mas ainda não entendo esse código direito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: que medo do nome dessas variáveis, a, b, c...

Comment: você tem o link do gauge para disponibilizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui tem uma explicação de como utilizar o gauge.

```
var target = document.getElementById('foo'); // Elemento onde o gauge deve ser criado
var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts); // Criar gauge
gauge.maxValue = 200; // Valor maximo
gauge.setMinValue(0);  // Valor minimo
gauge.set(175); // Valor a ser exibido
```

Quando você utiliza o new Gauge, você passa como parâmetro o elemento HMTL onde o gráfico vai ser criado. Utilizando o método setOptions, você passa como parâmetro um objeto com as configurações do gráfico.
Para definir os valores, depois de criar o gauge, você utiliza os métodos minValue, maxValue, (valores inicial e final) e set, para exibir o valor que você quer.

Aqui tem um exemplo completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>GaugeJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>GaugeJS</h1>
    <canvas id="foo" style="width: 380px; height: 150px"></canvas>
    <script src="http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var opts = {
  angle: 0, 
  lineWidth: 0.44,
  radiusScale: 1, // Raio relativo
  pointer: {
    length: 0.6, // // Relativo ao raio do Gauge
    strokeWidth: 0.035, // Largura do traço
    color: '#000000' // Cor do ponteiro
  },
  limitMax: false,     // Se false, valor maximo aumenta automaticamente se valor > valor maximo
  limitMin: false,     // Se true, o valor mínimo será fixo
  colorStart: '#1ABC9C',   // Cores
  colorStop: '#1ABC9C',    
  strokeColor: '#F0F3F3',  
  generateGradient: true,
  highDpiSupport: true,  
  
 };
 var target = document.getElementById('foo'); // Elemento onde o gauge deve ser criado
 var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts); // Criar gauge
 gauge.maxValue = 200; // Valor maximo
 gauge.setMinValue(0);  // Valor minimo
 gauge.animationSpeed = 32; // Velocidade da animacao
 gauge.set(175); // Valor a ser exibido
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```